# npm publish - out of memory

Tags: node.js, memory, npm

I'm on Windows (and using nvm). I want to publish a ~200mb module to our private npm repo but I get

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I found out, that I should try to increase my memory usage. I'm not sure if I did it correctly because I'm on Windows and use nvm (currently using node v6.10.0), so my command looked like this:

`node --max-old-space-size=4096 C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.10.0\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js publish`

but I ran into the same issue.
While doing so, I had a look into my task manager and the node process only allocated ~1.4GB memory - so how can I still have an `out of memory` error when my memory limit isn't reached? And, of course, how can I publish my module?

Comment: Is this 64-bit Node?

Comment: @tadman yes it is

Comment: Have you tried using a gzipped version of your package? Also if you use Github you can just publish using the url to the repo.